# ContextMenu, get Parent TextBlock Id

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

ItemSource for the ListBox is a ObservableCollection of Animals. 
Each animal have a Name and a Id. Inside the TextBlock showing the name of the animal, I have a ContextMenu. When long tap, it shows a menu UnFollow. When clicking on that Menu it raises the UnFollow_OnClick event.

Now to my question, how can I in my code behind get the Id of the animal?

Have tried some different scenarios but cannot find any working solutions.

```
 <ListBox x:Name="AllAnimals" Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding AllAnimals}">
               <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                     <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}">
                           <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                              <toolkit:ContextMenu IsZoomEnabled="False">
                                    <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Unfollow" Click="UnFollow_OnClick" />
                              </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                           </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                        </TextBlock>
                     </StackPanel>
                  </DataTemplate>
               </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>

private void UnFollow_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{  

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work:

```
    private void UnFollow_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Animal animal = ((Animal)((sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext));

        MenuItem item = (sender as MenuItem);
        string itemValue = item.Header.ToString();

        if (itemValue == "Unfollow")
        {
            try
            {
                if (animal != null)
                {
                    // animal.Id
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 private void UnFollow_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var animal = AllAnimals.SelectedItem as Animal;
        if(animal==null) return;
        var id = animal.Id;
    }
```

Hope its help.

Comment: Using this approach it works sometimes, but mostly the animal object is null. Any ideas why?

Comment: add event handler to event ContextMenuIsOpened, and sender will be your listbox item. Then manually set this item as selected item of listbox. And that's all.